# Declare hash variable in loop

Tags: perl

I need to use a hash and loop in my code. Please see the sample code it's not working. i wanted to print the variable wafer, site and res side by side so it will look like this

```
1, 1, 63 
1, 2, -53 
1, 3, 9.47 
1, 4, 9.55 
1, 5, -8.32

my @wafer = ("1","1","1","1","1");
my @site = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
my @res = ("63","-53","9.47","9.55","-8.32");

my %hash;
foreach my $result(@res) {
    $hash{$wafer[0]}{$site[0]} = $result;
    last;
}

print "$wafer{$wafer[0]}{$site[0]} \n";
```

Comment: What do you expect your code to do, and what does it actually do?

Comment: Did you mean `print "$hash{$wafer[0]}{$site[0]} \n";` on the last line?

Comment: Also, if you run `last` unconditionally, you don't need a loop. You just always use `$result = $res[0];`.

Comment: I'm afraid that just showing us (broken?) code isn't very helpful. Please edit your question to add a description of what you expect to see. What output are you looking for?

Comment: i wanted to print the variable wafer, site and res side by side so it will look like this 1, 1, 63 then next row 1,  2,  -53 then 1, 3, 9.47  then 1, 4, 9.55 then lastly 1, 5, -8.32

Comment: @kayegabato: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58833082/edit) to add this new information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to iterate several arrays synchronously, iterate over the indices:

```
for my $index (0 .. $#wafer) {
    print "$wafer[$index] $site[$index] $res[$index]\n";
}
```

You also might want to build a hash keyed by the site (as it's the only unique value):

```
for my $index (0 .. $#wafer) {
    $hash{ $site[$index] } = { wafer => $wafer[$index],
                               res   => $res[$index] };
}
```

This will create a hash like this:

```
%hash = (
      '4' => {
               'res' => '9.55',
               'wafer' => '1'
             },
      '3' => {
               'wafer' => '1',
               'res' => '9.47'
             },
      '1' => {
               'res' => '63',
               'wafer' => '1'
             },
      '2' => {
               'res' => '-53',
               'wafer' => '1'
             },
      '5' => {
               'res' => '-8.32',
               'wafer' => '1'
             }
    );
```

Comment: for my $index (0 .. $#wafer) - may i ask what this $#wafer stands for?

Comment: @kayegabato: If you have an array called `@some_array_name` then Perl gives you an extra scalar variable, called `$#some_array_name` which always contains the value of the last index in the array (or -1 if the array is empty).