# how to use for loop in array of data

Tags: perl

I wanted to use for loop in my code, my objective is to print testnames[i] units[i] hilim[i] lolim[i]
Please see my sample data below.

```
  testnames     BV_N4       BV_N43      BV_P4    
    units       V 10/.18    V 10/.35    V 10/.18     
    hilim       8           13         -3.6 
    lolim       3.6         6          -8

for @testnames {
print "$testnames[i] $units[i] $hilim[i] $lolim[i]";
}
```

Comment: I think that you were [told how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58835507/4653379) just yesterday ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare hash variable in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833082/declare-hash-variable-in-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you were [told yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833082/declare-hash-variable-in-loop/58835507#58835507):

> When you want to iterate several arrays synchronously, iterate over the indices

```
for my $i (0 .. $#testnames) {
  print "$testnames[$i] $units[$i] $hilim[$i] $lolim[$i]";
}
```

Comment: i can see only  BV_N4  V 10/.18 8 3.6 not the rest of the data

Comment: @kayegabato: If the data is in the arrays, then my code will display it. If my code isn't displaying the data, then it isn't in the arrays. Of course, I don't know how you get from the input data in your question to the data supposedly being in the arrays, so I have no idea why the arrays aren't being populated correctly. If you have problems populating the arrays, you should probably ask another question about that.

Comment: i research and try this one for (my $i=0; $i <= $#testnames; $i++)  then it shows all the data

Comment: @kayegabato: I can think of no circumstances where `for (my $i=0; $i <= $#testnames; $i++)` isn't exactly equivalent to `for my $i (0 .. $#testnames)`.